# doctrine - single table inheritance and native query fails

Tags: doctrine-orm

In a symfony 2.8 app I have following class hierarchy configured as single table inheritance:

```
parent: App\Entity\AbstractUser 
child1: App\Entity\UserClient
child2: App\Entity\UserGuest
```

Further each class from above has a oneToOne relation to a class App\Entity\Profile.

Based on the above I have a native query on the **profiles** table joining the **users** table.
The goal is to get the profile data together with the related user data in one query.

It did work for a while but stopped working at some point. Probably after doctrine bundle update.

Now my code below throws the following exception: `The provided class "App\Entity\AbstractUser" is abstract, and can not be instantiated`.

What can I do to make it work again?

Here is my code:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('App\Entity\AbstractUser', 'br');
$rsm->addFieldResult('br', 'user_id', 'id');

$sql = "
    SELECT
        rsa.id AS profile_id,
        br.id AS user_id
    FROM profiles rsa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users br ON rsa.id = br.profile_id
";

try {
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $results = $query->getResult();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```

Here are the doctrine definitions:

```
// Resources/config/doctrine/AbstractUser.orm.yml
App\Entity\AbstractUser:
  type: entity
  table: users
  inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: type
    type: string
    length: 30
    nullable: false
  discriminatorMap:
    client: App\Entity\UserClient
    guest: App\Entity\UserGuest
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO

  # oneToOne association
  oneToOne:
    profile:
      targetEntity: App\Entity\Profile
      cascade: ['persist','remove']
      joinColumn:
        name: profile_id
        referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: false
        unique: false

// Resources/config/doctrine/UserClient.orm.yml
App\Entity\UserClient:
  type: entity

// Resources/config/doctrine/UserGuest.orm.yml
App\Entity\UserGuest:
  type: entity

// Resources/config/doctrine/Profile.orm.yml
App\Entity\Profile:
  type: entity
  table: profiles
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

Comment: `$rsm->addEntityResult('App\Entity\AbstractUser', 'br');` Does this line not cause the result mapper to attempt to create an instance of `AbstractUser` with the query results? Why not change AbstractUser to just User, have it be an Entity. The result mapper should recognize it being a discriminated type (based on config and column) and automagically join the mapped entity. (If `ResultSetMapping` does not support this, look into `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder`).

Comment: Also, [see here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance), last bullet point quoted: `If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains the lowercase short name of each class as key.` - So you can remove the `discriminatorMap` config and let Doctrine handle the creation of that internally.

Comment: Thx @rkeet. What do you mean by "Why not change AbstractUser to just User"? One of the child classes? I already tried that with e.g. `$rsm->addEntityResult('App\Entity\UserClient', 'br');` The query works but the result set contains only UserClient entities regardless what discriminator type the record is.

Comment: Make `User` an Entity. Not `abstract`, not a `MappedSuperclass`, but an instantiate-able Entity. If you then `$rsm->addEntityResult('App\Entity\User', 'br')` you _should_ get a result set of `User`, `UserClient` and `UserGuest` Entities. To prevent plain `User` of being created, just make sure it cannot be created by not making a `user/add` URI/endpoint.

Comment: @rkeet If I do so a followup problem arises: `Entity 'App\Entity\AbstractUser' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'App\Entity\AbstractUser' to be properly mapped in the inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make 'App\Entity\AbstractUser' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occurring`

Comment: Created an answer explaining MappedSuperclass and Table Inheritance. Hope that helps. Your followup problem is due to _having_ a DiscriminatorMap. Simplest solution: remove the map. (Really, just delete it).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using *either* of:

- DiscriminatorMap (Single or Class Table Inheritance)
- MappedSuperclass

Info on both [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

---

### MappedSuperclass

This is similar to PHP's abstract class. You **can not** instantiate this class. It is therefore a class which **must** be extended into something proper. As such you could have:

- AbstractUser
- Guest extends AbstractUser
- Admin extends AbstractUser

This would give you a few things:

- Some properties and functions are available for both (saves duplicate code - DRY)
- Gives the same "parent" class as an instance

#### Setup & use case

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    // getter / setter
}
```

This use case shows the usage of a common identifier for all entities in my own projects. It also gives an easy entry-point to validate whether or not a specific Entity is in my own projects or supplied by a vendor, doing:

```
if ($entity instanceof AbstractEntity) { ... }
```

### Single / Class Table Inheritance

Now, let's use the MappedSuperclass in Table Inheritance. We're going with the `JOINED` strategy in this example, but feel free to use whichever suits your needs best.

You have 3 classes, 2 of which are instantiable:

- UserClient
- UserGuest

Both stem from: AbstractUser

Now, let's say that "Guest" is the most limited user, we'll create that one first:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_guests")
 */
class Guest extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="display_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $displayName;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    protected $email; 

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $password;

    // getters / setters
}
```

So far so good.

Now, we have the need to create "Client". A client should have:

- displayName
- email
- password
- clientId

The first 3 are the same as for Guest. So, it might be wise to extend Guest. Will other things (e.g. functionality) be the same for either user type? Such as:

- way of logging in/out
- being an email recipient/sender
- etc.

If a lot of these use cases are the same, then we have a solid case for using Table Inheritance. So, update the Annotation for Guest, like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_guests")
 * 
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class Guest extends AbstractEntity { ... }
```

***NOTE***: We *do not declare* a `DiscriminatorMap`. Doctrine will handle this for us. [Per the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance):

> If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains the lowercase short name of each class as key.

Next, create the Client:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_clients")
 */
class Client extends Guest
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $clientId;

    // getters / setters
}
```

---

The SQL generated by Doctrine for these 2, as an example, is this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_guests
(
  id           INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  display_name VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
  email        VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
  password     LONGTEXT                    NOT NULL,
  discr        VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_2843A78FE7927C74 (email),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_clients
(
  id        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  client_id VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE user_clients
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_58C5307EBF396750 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user_guests (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Shown visually, that's:

[image: Tables for use-case shown visually]

---

Now you can also add in your Profile Entity very easily. You simply add it to your Guest user, with a [OneToOne bi-directional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) relation.

So, add to your Guest:

```
// other properties

/**
 * @var Profile
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="Guest")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $profile;

// getter / setter
```

At this point though, you might wish to consider renaming "Guest" to plain "User", as using that for a name could be less confusing in the future. "User" is usually already a pretty limited member, similar to a Guest (the difference usually being that a "Guest" *is not* a registered User and a User *is*).

Now you can simply do:

```
$profile->getGuest() // or ->getUser() if you renamed
// Returns instance of Guest (might be child instance: Client)

$guest->getProfile() // returns Profile
$client->getProfile() // returns Profile

$user = new Guest();
$user instanceof Guest ? true : false; // true
$user instanceof Client ? true : false; // false

$user = new Client();
$user instanceof Guest ? true : false; // true
$user instanceof Client ? true : false; // true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed instructions. Its great to see so much commitment. Don't get me wrong, but I get the inheritance basics pretty well I guess. And I asked for SINGLE_TABLE inheritance explicitly. On top I can not see anything wrong in my yaml definitions. Custom discriminatorMap is not required but supported and correctly defined I think (btw. I removed it - no effect).
I suspect my problem is not in the inheritance definition BUT in Native Query Builder options inside the query logic code. If you can concentrate on that, this would be much appreciated.